# Generar archivo .apk desde Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Saben si es posible generar el ejecutable .apk de android para subir al Play Store, desde eclipse, teniendo el código fuente java?

Comment: Hola Carlos, bienvenido. Pasate por el [tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender como funciona este sitio. Esta pregunta deberia reformularse para que no sea "saben si es posible"  y quede como "Cuales son los pasos". Ya que si te contestamos: "si, es posible" de que te sirve¿?  Un saludo

Comment: Acá hay información que te puede servir: http://www.linuxhispano.net/2012/06/26/exportar-a-apk-una-aplicacion-android-en-eclipse/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generar un .APK en eclipse es posible mediante,

`Android Tools` > `Export Signed Application Package` o `Export _Unsigned Application Package` (si no requires tu .apk firmado con el Keystore).

**Para subir a la Play Store es necesario firmar la aplicación con tu Keystore** por lo cual te sugiero usar la opción `Export Signed Application Package` , esto requerirá del Keystore y su password.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Sí, es posible. Debes hacer clic derecho en tu proyecto:

`Android`>`Android Tools`>`Export Signed Application Package`

Necesitarás generar una KeyStore que te pedirá durante el proceso, es sencillo pero el archivo generado guardalo porque a la hora de generar una nueva versión para poder actualizar en Play Store necesitarás exportar con esa KeyStore.